# Eloquent not eager loading big relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, out-of-memory, eager-loading

In a e-commerce I have a model Products, with probably around 20 relation with other parts of the site. One of this relation is a *belongsToManny* relation called relatedProducts, which points to the table Products itself.

```
    public function relatedProducts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_related_products', 'product_id', 'related_product_id');
    }
```

The endpoint to display all the products (paginated in 100s) must eagerload all the product relations, which is fine, but when loading the relatedProducts is exausts the memory, since most of the products are related to other 200 products, so the object gets too big.

If I paginate in chunks of 50 (for instance) it works fine.

I try loop through the products to load the relation manually but it did not improve it.
Does anybody have a suggestion in what to do to load all of it?

that's the error i am getting

> Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8192 bytes) {"userId":3,"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException(code: 1): Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8192 bytes) at /vagrant/laravel/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:158)"}

Oh! If i improve the memory limit with `ini_set('memory_limit', '300M')` it works, but i really want a different solution.

Comment: How about not using objects? A simple, multidimensional  PHP array with only key-value pairs would take less memory

Comment: Do you really need to load all related products?  What about limiting to 5, or 10, or whatever?

Comment: Products::with('relatedProducts')->paginate(10);
with this query your performance will be so well

Comment: Also, piece of advice, consider using raw query for a lot of data, it have helped me a lot. I have done an experiment where 1K data with multiple joins using eloquent costs 1 whole minute, while raw query only costs 10 seconds.